# Vulkan Memory Alignment for Uniform Buffers

Tags: c++, c++17, shader, vulkan, memory-alignment

I'm following the online tutorial: [vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Uniform_buffers/Descriptor_pool_and_sets) where the author is adding in the functionality for Descriptor Pools and Descriptor Sets.

I'm using Vulkan `v1.2.135.0` and my Shader's are set to `#version 450`

I'm nearly finished this part of the tutorial and I'm able to render a spinning square and I'm getting no errors from Vulkan Layers when I compile and run in Debug mode.

I'm near the bottom of the page provided by the link above where he introduces a `glm::vec2` within the `UniformBufferOjbect` struct and a `vec2` within the same corresponding struct within `shader.vert`.

He changed these:

```
// Defined in C++ file
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 proj;
};

// Defined in shader.vert
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;
```

To the following:

```
// Defined in C++ file
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::vec2 foo;
    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 proj;
};

// Defined in shader.vert
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    vec2 foo;
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;
```

I followed the example and recompiled the shader using the provided tool to convert it to an `SPV` binary. And as he suggests there is nothing rendered on the screen as this has to do with `memory-alignment` that Vulkan requires...

He briefly explains the memory alignment issues by stating how to fix this issue. There were two things he suggests doing... The first is to use C++11's or greater `alignas(16)` modifier.

He then states that if we are to change our `UniformBufferObject` to the following:

```
// Defined in C++ file
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::vec2 foo;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 proj;
};
```

Then compile and run the program again that it should render correctly, however, I'm still getting a black screen.

He also suggests using `glm`'s `#define GLM_FORCE_DEFAULT_ALIGNED_GENTYPES` directive before including its header files in which I did. It is still not rendering anything to the screen...

I even modified the `UniformBufferObject` to:

```
// Defined in C++ file
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::vec2 foo;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 view;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 proj;
};
```

And still, nothing is rendering. I don't know why this isn't working as suggested by the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

a vec2 must have an alignement of 8

- a float an alignement of 4
- a vec2 an alignement of 8
- a vec3, vec4, mat4 an alignement of 16

you must correct like that :

```cpp
struct UniformBufferObject {
    alignas(8) glm::vec2 foo;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 view;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 proj;
};
```

UBO use the rule std140, you can check this rule for know how to deal with it :)

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, the UBO structures should be vec4-aligned. Your first field of the structure breaks this alignment.

The quick(est) fix can be

```
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::vec4 foo;
    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 proj;
};
```

In the shader just use the `ubo.foo.xy` swizzle to get vec2.

Of course, the shader code should also be modified to

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    vec4 foo;
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;
```

Comment: I understand that... It's just that I was following the tutorial and as the author suggested by using `alignas(16)`  and that it should work, but it didn't... that's what was striking me curious... I don't know if it was because of the change of the API version, driver versions of cards, C++ compiler versions, etc...

Comment: Probably because of the alignment in the driver. My guess would be you are using AMD's Radeon.

Comment: Not quite, I'm using an NVidia Geforce GTX 750 TI by EVGA.